# Re: Construction of a non-empty perfect set of real numbers without rationals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, irrational-numbers, descriptive-set-theory

We consider the set $[e, \pi]$.

Let $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...\}$ be the enumeration of the rationals in $[e, \pi]$. $r_n= \min\{|x_n-e|,|\pi-x_n|\} $

We can enclose $x_n$ by $I_n=(a_n,b_n)=(x_n-\frac{r_n}{2^{100n}},x_n+\frac{r_n}{2^{100n}})\subsetneq [e, \pi] $.

[Note: The irrationality of the endpoints will be maintained for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $r_n$ is irrational].

$A=\displaystyle[e, \pi] \setminus\{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n\}$ is closed.

Suppose, $N'_\delta(c)\cap A=\emptyset$ for some $\delta>0$, i.e $c $ must lie on the "edge" of two consecutive intervals.  .

At least for two intervals $I_s$ and $I_t$, it happens. For this to occur, the intervals must lie on two "opposite sides" of $c$ since $c \in A$ and $c \notin \bigcup I_n$.

We must have $\displaystyle x_s-\frac{r_s}{2^{100s}}=x_t+\frac{r_t}{2^{100t}}$. But it is not possible in any case since $x_s-x_t$ is rational and $\displaystyle\frac{r_s}{2^{100s}}+\frac{r_t}{2^{100t}}$ is irrational.

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate question. Many other constructions has been posted on this site. But I want something different and I want it to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it more abstract and the construction is easier.

All you need is a family of compact subsets (intervals if you like) $A_s$ where $s$ is running over all finite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s and say $A_\varepsilon = [0,1]$, say (where $\varepsilon$ is the empty sequence) and such that

- $A_{s0} \cap A_{s1} = \emptyset$ and $A_{s0} \subseteq A_s$ and $A_{s1} \subseteq A_s$ for all sequences $s$.
- $\operatorname{diam}(A_s) \le \frac{1}{2^{|s|}}$ where $|s|$ is the length of the sequence $s$.
- $f(s) \notin A_{s}$ for some bijection $f$ from the finite $0$-$1$ sequences to $\Bbb Q$ (which exists as both sets are countable).

(The usual Cantor set construction has $A_{0}=[0,\frac13]$, $A_{00}=[0,\frac19]$, $A_{01}=[\frac{2}{9},\frac13]$ etc.) It's not hard to see how to fulfill the first 2 conditions recursively (take two disjoint closed subintervals of $A_s$) and the third condition takes almost no effort: just shrink a bit two avoid two additional points when splitting $A_s$ into $A_{s0}$ and $A_{s1}$ in the recursivion step.

Then if $x$ is an infinite sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s (so $s \in 2^\omega$) and $x\mid n$ is the finite sequence of the first $n$ of them, $$A:= \bigcup_{x \in 2^\omega} \bigcap_{n \in \omega} A_{s\mid n}$$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set (and thus perfect) and the final condition ensures that no member of $\Bbb Q$ lies in $A$.

This borrows from standard techniques from descriptive set theory (see Kechris' book "Classical Descriptive Set Theory" for more explanations and in depth results in this spirit).

Comment: I don't have much idea regarding homeomorphism at this stage, but I'll come back to this answer for future reference and this method is surely better. But I want to know whether my method works or not as well. Could you please go through it ? Just a little request.

Comment: @justanotheruser Your writeup is too chaotic too judge, really. Make it more systematic. Write it up as a recursive construction so first interval $A_0=[e,\pi]$; what are the two closed intervals in the next stage, etc.? Presumably $[e,e+t]$ and $[\pi-s, \pi]$ for small enough $s,t>0$ so that the endpoints are irrational, and do not contain the first 2 rationals of your enumeration, etc.

Comment: That is precisely what I have tried. But instead of recursion, I have collectively enclosed each rational. It can be made arbitrarily small since rationals have measure $0$.

Comment: I have struggled at showing that any $c \in A$ acts as a limit point of $A$. What I meant by "edge" was that for some $\delta>0$, $(c-\delta,c) \subset \cup I_n$ and $(c,c+\delta) \subset \cup I_n$. So, $c$ is the only missing point. Then I tried to show that it can never happen. 

For this to occur, the "endpoint" of one open interval must coincide with the "starting point" of another, and at their junction, lies the point $c$.

Comment: @justanotheruser I'm not convinced your argument works, we get a closed but maybe not perfect set wthout rationals...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with decimal expansions. Let $E$ be the set of real numbers whose decimal expansions have the form

$$.1 Z_1 a_1 1 Z_2 a_2 1 Z_3 a_3 \dots.$$

Here $Z_n$ is a block of $n$ zeros and $a_n\in \{0,1\}.$

Each number in $E$ is irrational because its decimal expansion has infinitely many $1$'s and arbitrarily large blocks of $0$'s. And $E$ is closed because if a sequence $x_n$ in $E$ converges to $x,$ then the expansions of the $x_n$ converge in each slot to that of $x.$ This implies $x$ has an expansion of the required form, hence $x\in E.$

Let $x = .1  Z_1  a_1 1 Z_2 a_2 \dots \in E.$ For $n=1,2,\dots,$ define $x_n\in E$ to be the number whose expansion is the same as that for $x,$ except that $a_n$ is replaced by $1-a_n.$ Then the $x_n$ are distinct and converge to $x.$ Thus $E$ is perfect as desired.